# My Hard Drive isn't Working

Tags: windows-xp, laptop, usb, external-hard-drive

I never use Safely Remove Hardware with Windows XP. 
It has been working for me for years with my SD card, mouse, hard drive and memory stick. My hard drive has a USB cable and power cord so I can hook it up to any desktop hard drive. Now my hard drives don't  like this and I did not know this till now.

I am always careful and to wait till it is all finish accessing the USB before I unplug it. Now three of my hard drives can't be seen by Windows, though the others still work. when I hook it up to another computer it works fine.

I use the same USB cable to hook up all of my hard drives one at a time. So my USB cable is good. I think that when I unplugged the hard drive this one time, it had a file it still wanted to see and now only this drive does not work only this computer.

Then the same thing happens to my other two hard drive after I used it for a week with the same cables.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Give this Microsoft fixit utility a try...http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Tips-for-solving-problems-with-USB-devices

Comment: Are you plugging them into the same usb port? Maybe try a different port?

Comment: All My stuff works in all USB ports.

Answer (score 1):

With the information given it's more likely a hardware problem than a software problem.

1. Check the Device Manager (hit <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and type in `devmgmt.msc` and hit Enter). Does the drive show up? If not, it's possible the drive failed, in which case you'll want to send it off to DriveSavers if you have the money.
2. Replace the USB cable. You said it works for other drives, but in troubleshooting you want to check every possibility, by order of time taken up and success rate. Replacing USB cables falls under this.
3. It could be drivers. Look up drivers for your hard drive off the Internet (express **extreme caution** here, only go to the official site or use [WOT](http://www.mywot.com/)). Uninstall and reinstall them, reboot.

Windows doesn't kill your drive because of a measly Delayed Write Error. Most hard drives use the NTFS filesystem and NTFS keeps track of what breaks down for error checking.

Comment: All the drives work on another computer. so I have not lost my stuff.

Comment: What is different about those drives from the others? Anything in particular?

Comment: I have one Laptop hard drive and 6 IDE desk top hard drives all exteral USB. 40G 20G 40G 7G 20G 4G 80G DVD Bruner

Comment: Which two failed?

Comment: 20G 40G DVD Burner but if I hook up to desk top it works fine   I am using a USB cable that can hook up right up to a desk top IDE or SATA hard drive